# Android 8.0+ java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent

Tags: android, android-service

Android Studio 3.2

```
public class GcmWakefulBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    private static String TAG;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), GcmIntentService_.class.getName());
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp))); // crash here
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}

public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {

    private static String TAG = GcmIntentService.class.getName();

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    }
}
```

On **Android 8.0-** success work. App is on background.

But on **Android 8.0+** the app is crash with error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.myproject.app, PID: 6506
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.myproject.app.gcm.GcmWakefulBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x1000010 pkg=com.myproject.app cmp=com.myproject.app/.gcm.GcmIntentService_ (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{27efe68 u0a164 RCVR idle change:idle|uncached procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3194)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(Unknown Source:0)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1672)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x1000010 pkg=com.myproject.app cmp=com.myproject.app/.gcm.GcmIntentService_ (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{27efe68 u0a164 RCVR idle change:idle|uncached procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}
     at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1521)
     at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1477)
     at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:650)
     at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:650)
     at com.myproject.app.gcm.GcmWakefulBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(GcmWakefulBroadcastReceiver.java:44)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3187)
     ... 8 more
 broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED
```

Crash in this line:

```
 startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp))); // crash here
```

My app must work on **Android 4.4+**

Comment: Use JobIntentService Instead of IntentService.

Comment: @DhavalPatel My app must work on Android 4.4+. Not only on Android 8.0

Comment: JobIntentService  is backward compatible

Answer (score 0):

Use JobIntentService Instead of IntentService.

```
public class GcmIntentService extends JobIntentService {

    private static String TAG = GcmIntentService.class.getName();

    public static void startService(Context context) {
        enqueueWork(context, GcmIntentService.class, 1001, new Intent());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleWork(Intent intent) {

    }

}
```

And From your Receiver:

```
public class GcmWakefulBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    private static String TAG;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        GcmIntentService.startService(context);
    }
}
```

> If you are using GcmWakefulBroadcastReceiver just for starting the service then, You do not need to use WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
>   When running on Android O, the JobScheduler will take care of wake
>   locks for you (holding a wake lock from the time you enqueue work
>   until the job has been dispatched and while it is running).

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/JobIntentService

Comment: I need to pass Intent from GcmWakefulBroadcastReceiver to GcmIntentService.onHandleWork(@NonNull Intent intent). How I can do this?

Comment: @Alexei you can modify startService method in GcmIntentService as per your needs. Check the last parameter is of intent(instead of new Intent() you can pass intent object from broadcast receciver).